# Dynamically loading SubReport data in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

This is in SSRS 2008.
I've created a report with a tablix, embedded in the tablix there is a subreport. This subreport contains a lot of information (and I mean a lot – it takes more than 45 sec to load it).

I don’t want to show it, or to be more precise – to process/load the data when the report initially runs. Note that I dont want to just not display it - because then all the data is still processed at initial load time.
Instead, I only want the subreport to be processed (and the data pulled down), individually, when I display it (e.g. clicking a + sign to toggle it, or any other option such as clicking an image/ link, while staying in the same report). I also don’t want to open the subreport in a different tab or something like that....

Does anyone know a solution? Maybe there is an onLoad method, dynamic subreport or something like that?
I tried looking into the DataElementOutput attribute, but that's readOnly... anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as it turns out, the problem was in fact because I had the subreport repeated for each row in the parent report. Thus, the subreport was called numerous times...
And according to MS, there is no way to dynamically process individual subreports. Had to solve this issue by splitting out the subreport (at least the data-heavy parts) to a seperate page. :(

Answer (score 1):

Before you jump through a lot of hoops to implement a workaround, have you analyzed the execution plan for the query which is delivers the data for the subreport?  If you haven't, it's worth it to see if performance can be improved by adding a covering index which will help the query optimizer to deliver the data quickly.

Hope this helps,

Bill

Comment: exactly, 45 seconds is horrible.

Comment: Thanks, and here I was looking forward to my Tumbleweed badge... ;-)  But yes, the query itself runs beautifully - returns results almost immediately. The index is a good idea, regardless, but that's not where my problem is.